# bash: or (`-o`) operatorator in `[[` (double square bracket)

Tags: bash, shell

(This question probably has been asked before but is very difficult to search due to the symbols...)

The `bash` manual did not make it clear whether `[[` (double square bracket keyword <- SEO) supports the `-o` (or) opperator. When I tried I got `-bash: syntax error in conditional expression`, but I can't quite believe this feature is mission.

Can anyone cite something to confirm this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man bash`, chapter *SHELL GRAMMAR*, explains that you can combine expressions in `[[ … ]]` by using the operators `( expression )` (parentheses), `! expression` (negation), `expression1 && expression2` (boolean and) and `expression1 || expression2` (boolean or; listed in descending order of priority). Assuming the manual is complete, `-o` is not valid syntax for `[[ … ]]`.